# unable to get right output from spliting int arrays

Tags: c#

I have goggled and looked various threads at this website and I am still not getting this right.

**Objective**

Would like to split int arrays in 3 groups

**Problem**

I am getting an output...

```
       1
       4
       7
```

instead of...

```
      [1,2,3]
      [4,5,6]
      [7,8,9]
```

**1st attempt**

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int[] arraya = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
      Array.Sort(arraya);
      int a = 0;
      int divideBya = 3;
      var resulta = arraya.GroupBy(s => a++ / divideBya).Select(g => g.ToArray()).ToArray();
      foreach(var item in resulta)
      {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", item[0]);
      }
  }
```

**2nd attempt**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int u = 0;
        int divideByb = 3;
        IEnumerable<List<int>> groupedObjects = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).GroupBy(x => u++ / divideByb)
                                        .Select(group => group.ToList()).ToList();
        foreach (var item in groupedObjects)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}", item[0]);
        }
     }
```

Can someone point me to the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: your first attempt you're only outputting the first index of your new array "item[0]". try "{0},{1},{2}" in your writeline with item[0], item[1]. item[2]

Comment: @Skintkingle - Thanks that solved the problem. I didn't know that.

Comment: please consider marking Renes answer as the solution. it's a much nicer way to do what I suggested to you. :)

Comment: @Skintkingle - OK I will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code seems almost correct. Your main problem is your output:

```
foreach (var item in groupedObjects)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", item[0]);
}
```

You only output the first element of each array. Try this:

```
foreach (var items in groupedObjects)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", items));
```

Comment: Damnit if only I wrote my comment as an answer! :P

Comment: @Skintkingle Your comment would work yes, though Rene's solution is more elegant, better code.

Comment: @Andrew I know. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your writeline statement to:

```
Console.WriteLine($"[{item[0]},{item[1]},{item[2]}]");
```